# How can I create a continuous text loop in React Konva?

Tags: react-konva

Is it possible to mimic the CSS marquee-style property in React Konva?

I did something like this:

- tween animate text from x={300} position to xposfin
- SetInterval play and reset the text on screen

but I would like that the text fit only in rect.

```
    import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    import Konva, { Easings } from "konva";
    import { Rect, Text, Group } from "react-konva";
    import { useTextWidth } from "@tag0/use-text-width";
```

```
    export const InfiniteloopFUN = (props) => {
      const textinfoRef = useRef(null);
      const txt = "continuous infinite text loop";
      let txtwidth = useTextWidth({ text: txt, font: "20px sans-serif" });
      let xposfin = 200 - txtwidth;
    
      useEffect(() => {
        var tween = new Konva.Tween({
          node: textinfoRef.current,
          easing: Easings.Linear,
          duration: 5,
          x: xposfin,
        });
    
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          tween.reset();
          tween.play();
        }, 5000);
      });
    
      return (
        <Group>
          <Rect x={200} y={46} width={100} height={20} fill="black" />
          <Text x={300} y={46} fill="orange" fontSize={20} text={txt} ref={textinfoRef} />
        </Group>
      );
    };
```

Tanks
Gino

Answer (score 2):

You can use clipping to fit text into react. Approach with tween + interval is good. But also you can use built-in "onFinish" callback of tween.

```js
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { useTextWidth } from "@tag0/use-text-width";
import { Stage, Layer, Rect, Text, Group } from "react-konva";
import Konva from "konva";

const App = () => {
  const textinfoRef = React.useRef(null);
  const txt = "continuous infinite text loop";
  let txtwidth = useTextWidth({ text: txt, font: "20px sans-serif" });
  let xposfin = -txtwidth;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    var tween = new Konva.Tween({
      node: textinfoRef.current,
      easing: Konva.Easings.Linear,
      duration: 5,
      x: xposfin,
      onFinish: () => {
        tween.reset();
        tween.play();
      }
    });
    tween.play();

    return () => {
      tween.destroy();
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
      <Layer>
        <Group
          x={200}
          y={46}
          clipX={0}
          clipY={0}
          clipWidth={100}
          clipHeight={50}
        >
          <Rect width={100} height={20} fill="black" />
          <Text
            x={100}
            fill="orange"
            fontSize={20}
            text={txt}
            ref={textinfoRef}
          />
        </Group>
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
};

const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-jones-62yu6o?file=/src/index.js